# Why does the 'setAttribute' function not work with variable value?

Tags: angular

I want to set 'margin-left' attribute via the .ts file.
this is how I did this:

```
document.getElementById('pesek').setAttribute('margin- 
left',this.left+'%');
```

now, the 'left' variable is type number, and I want it in percents so I add it.
I also tried with string type variable and it's not worked either.

Comment: Try backtick string interpolation like..  ` ${ this.left } % `

Answer (score 1):

You are using angular, better would be to use the style property binding. The `setAttribute` is used to.. well, set an attribute :)

template:

```
<h1 id="pesek" [style.margin-left.%]="left">
  Riki
</h1>
```

And in your component you can assign the `this.left` like you are used to

<sub>I suggest you do some research in basic JS first, before jumping into a full blown framework like angular, otherwise I'm afraid it's going to be too overwhelming for you</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not writing the code of what you want to achieve.

If you are using `setAttribute('margin-left','50%')`, Then this is not going to change your element style. This will be applied to an element as -

```
<h1 id="pesek" margin-left="50%"> Anuj Raghuvanshi </h1>
```

If you really want to apply `margin-left` Then you will need to do as -

```
document.getElementById("pesek").style.marginLeft = "50%";
OR
document.getElementById("pesek").style.marginLeft = this.left+"%";
```

Output -

```
<h1 id="pesek" style="margin-left: 50%;">
      Anuj Raghuvanshi
</h1>
```

That's All what you need to do is. *Happy Coding :)*